# Undefined index: subject in PHP $_GET

Tags: php

I need your help with php code. I usethe switch and $ _GET to jump between the substages but still show me the **Undefined index: subject in line 125**. Would you help me?

Here is a section of code:

```
    switch ($_GET['subject'])   //line 125
    {
       case "jednotky":
       include "jednotky.php";
       break;

       case "mapa":
       include "mapa.php";
       break;

       case "druh":
       include "druh.php";
       break;
```

Comment: If you are using php 7+  you can do `switch ($_GET['subject'] ?? null)`, otherwise you need to check it before the switch: `if (!isset($_GET['subject']) { //do something }`

Comment: thanke you som much